# SKStoreProductViewController in iOS 8 Actions Extension

Tags: ipad, storekit, ios-extensions

I'm working on an iOS Action Extension that's capable of showing an `SKStoreProductViewController`. Action Extensions are capable of showing in two sizes, either full screen (`NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation` set to `YES`) or in a small centered window in the screen (set to `NO`). I'm opting for the minimal window in the middle, my extension doesn't warrant use of the full screen.

When I show an `SKStoreProductViewController` modally within my extension as prescribed it ends up large and clipped in the center of the action extension. Has anybody else encountered this or found a way around it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation` set to `YES`, the extension behaves like a `UIModalPresentationStyleFormSheet` thus:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 540, height: 620)  
}
```

Note that the extension is displayed full screen on an iPhone (as expected).

References:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/SystemExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW35
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIModalPresentationFormSheet